# Sympy python circumference

Tags: python, sympy

I need to display a circumference. In order to do that I thought I could calculata for a lot of `x` the two values of `y`, so I did:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.abc import x,y
f = x**2 + y**2 - 1
a = x - 0.5
sy.solve([f,a],[x,y])
```

and this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 484, in
 solve
    solution = _solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 749, in
 _solve
    result = solve_poly_system(polys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/polysys.py", line 40, in
solve_poly_system
    return solve_biquadratic(f, g, opt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/polysys.py", line 48, in
solve_biquadratic
    G = groebner([f, g])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 5308, i
n groebner
    raise DomainError("can't compute a Groebner basis over %s" % domain)
DomainError: can't compute a Groebner basis over RR
```

How can I calculate the `y`'s values ?

Comment: What did you install Sympy with? There seem to be complications when trying to install it via PIP

Comment: @tehmisvh, Try installing with pip again.  That issue should have been fixed with the release of 0.7.2 Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me; maybe the solution is as simple as upgrading?

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.2'
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y
>>> f = x**2 + y**2 - 1
>>> a = x - 0.5
>>> sy.solve([f,a],[x,y])
[(0.500000000000000, -0.866025403784439), (0.500000000000000, 0.866025403784439)]
```

[Although if I needed to draw a circle or an arc I'd use `r cos(theta), r sin(theta)` instead, to make it easier to get the points in the right order.]

Comment: I've an older version, i'll try to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use rational numbers to get an exact answer (and avoid that bug)

```
In [22]: a = x - Rational(1,2)

In [23]: sy.solve([f,a],[x,y])
Out[23]:
⎡⎛        ___⎞  ⎛       ___⎞⎤
⎢⎜     -╲╱ 3 ⎟  ⎜     ╲╱ 3 ⎟⎥
⎢⎜1/2, ──────⎟, ⎜1/2, ─────⎟⎥
⎣⎝       2   ⎠  ⎝       2  ⎠⎦
```